# Two Problems I'm having with UIButton and UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage, modal-dialog

I haven't been programming on the iPhone for very long, but I'm picking it up slowly by googling problems I get. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find an answer for these.

I have started a new View-based application in Xcode 3.2.2 and immediately added the following files: myUIView.m and myUIView.h, which are subclasses of UIView. In Interface Builder, I set the subclass of the default UIView to be myUIView.

I made a button in the drawRect method.

**Problem one:** The title of the button only appears AFTER I click the screen, why?

**Problem two:** I want the button to produce the modalview - is this possible?

The code is as follow:

```
#import "myUIView.h"
@implementation myUIView
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
    [button setTitle:@"butty" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:button];
}

-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Button pressed");
    //present modal view somehow..?
}
```

I can't see how to post attachments, but if anyone thinks it will help I can upload the source.

Many thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawRect`: is for custom drawing.  You won't often need to do that.  Your button won't be drawn until it gets sent `drawRect`:, probably in the next iteration of the run loop (ie, when you click on the view).

If you want a button on your view, either drag it there using IB, or move the code from `drawRect:` to `viewDidLoad`.

You present a modal view from a view controller by:

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Do this in the action method your button sends to your view controller.  This should indicate to you that you need to take a look at your application design.

Comment: Ok that's a good method. It does seem to draw the button and background colour, just not the title or background image...

Any ideas for my second problem?

Thanks, A

Comment: It seems that viewDidLoad isn't a method a subclass of UIView responds to.I put the button in awakeFromNib instead. My code now looks like this:

-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
 newNib *myModalVC = [[newNib alloc] init];
 [self presentModalViewController:myModalVC animated:YES];
}

However, this doesn't work as "'myUIView' may not respond to '-presentModalViewController:animated:'"...

The project requires several buttons being created dynamically, so I suppose they have to be made in the UIView subclass, but I cannot call the modal view as that requires a UIViewController..*stuck :-?*

Comment: Note the last comment in my answer.  You really should have a view controller.  The role of a view is to draw itself; the view controller is responsible for transitions and coordinating data.  It is likely that the code you have really belongs in a view controller.

Comment: Thanks for that Paul; I did try putting it all in the ViewController, and making the button in the viewDidLoad method, however I run in to further problems because the UIViewController doesn't like "[self addSubview:button];" --- presumably there is an alternate method of creating the button I have yet to find..?

Thanks for helping me with this. A

Comment: A viewcontroller has a view property, therefore:

[self.view addSubview:button];

will work.